# ejs send variable to partial

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Scoured SO and google and the EJS site, couldn't find anything. If you have links to docs, please share.

I have a view called rooms.ejs and I load it this way:

```
  app.get('/rooms', function(req, res){
      RoomProvider.findAll(function(error, rooms){
        res.render('rooms', {
            locals: {
                title: 'List of rooms',
                rooms: rooms
            },
            layout:'simple'
        });
      });
  });
```

This is what I have inside that view (rooms.ejs): `<%- partial('room', rooms) %>`

The partial prints `<%= room.owner %>`. Works well.

I tried to **rename** the partial to rooms_partial, but now I have no idea what variable names get sent over `<%= room.owner %>` no longer works, `<%= rooms_partial.owner %>`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

TJ answered w/ this:

> camel-cased as roomsPartial, also res.render(foo, { rooms: rooms, title: '..', layout: 'simple' }) no need for locals:

Comment: Can you expand on this answer? It's rather cryptic.

Comment: I haven't touched this in a long time, but from what i remember, i tried to add a partial with underscores (rooms_partial.owner), but the correct way is camelcase (roomsPartial.owner) - not sure if this is still the case